# getting and storing user ip address javascript

Tags: forms, ip

I am a newby of javascript and in general programming. I have a google site and I would like to record the ip of the users submitting a form from the site. I saw, googling around that it is possible to use external service to obtain the ip address but I am trying to figure out how to set up a script (a javascript i suppose) in my site to accomplish the task.

In particular, what i need is the following:

1) a script from within the site has to get the ip address. I have found the following code in your forum that should do the job.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getip(json){
    alert(json); // alerts the ip address
  }


</script>

<script type="application/javascript" 
       src="http://www.anotherdomain.com/file.php? callback=getip"> 
</script>
```

How can I call it from a javascript function?

2) after getting the ip address I would like to fill with it a text area of the form and at its submission it should be sent to a google spreadsheet.
How can I get the ip output and send it to the textbox using javascript code?

Comment: This code is calling a server which you would have to have. And implement responding to JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var ip ; 
   $.ajax({
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
        ip = location.ip;
        $("textarea").val(ip);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you give a little explanation to say why this answers the question?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutley right that you can get a users IP address only by using external sources. Let's do it using [ipify.org!](https://www.ipify.org/)

So the check out the documentation here. There you will find that you need 2 things.

1. set the `<script>` after your HTML body has loaded as follows;

`<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP" defer></script>`

notice that the `<script>` tag will contact ipify.com and return the users IP address that is then pass to our JavaScript function called getIP() as JSONP.

2. Set the function below, here is one that I wrote that sets the value of a `<textarea>` in a `<div>`;

```js
         function getIP(json){
            document.getElementById("ipaddress").value = json.ip;
         }
```

this is the `<div>`:

```html
<div style="display: none;">
    <label>Ip address is:</label>
    <textarea id="ipaddress"></textarea>
</div>
```

Notice that I set the `<style>` to be; `display: none;` and the `id="ipaddress"` for the `<textarea>`. This will set that `<div>` to not display to your user and It makes it much easer to pass our IP address to our server/database. Like this:

```js
function submit(){
        let someValue = document.getElementById('someValue').value;
        let someotherValue = document.getElementById('someotherValue').value;
        let ip = document.getElementById('ipaddress').value;
       var formData = {
         someValue,someotherValue,ip 
       }
       google.script.run.serverSideFunction(formData)
       }
```